# Error while writing static function?

Tags: c++, linux

Error while writing static function.
static int function_name ( const Reference< data_type>* ptr)
{
}

when i wrote a static functin which takes Reference pointer then ir gives me following error 
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Reference' with no type
error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is complaining because it doesn't know what a `Reference<T>` is.  Either you've forgotten to `#include` the header file that it is defined in, or you've forgotten to forward-declare it.

Comment: thansk i got solution. i forget to write full path of Reference type

Answer (score 0):

You presumably mean Reference to be a template but the compiler doesn't see it as one.